# determine the lack of internet(retrofit)

Tags: android, retrofit

i use retrofit library. And if i  lose internet connection, i have error. But i have problem. if i turn off wifi and send request to server after some time i have error. But if i send request at once i have timeout but internet disable. I think it is because internet off at once. Is it possible to immediately determine that the Internet was gone?

now i use this

```
public final class SkipUrlConnectionClient extends UrlConnectionClient {
        @Override
        protected HttpURLConnection openConnection(Request request) throws IOException {
            HttpURLConnection connection = super.openConnection(request);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
            connection.setReadTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
            return connection;
        }
    }


private RestAdapter.Builder getBuilder(RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor) {
        RestAdapter.Builder builder = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setEndpoint(BuildConfig.ROOT_URL_SKIP)
                .setClient(new SkipUrlConnectionClient())
                .setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor)
                .setConverter(new JacksonConverter());
        builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL);
        return builder;
    }
```

Comment: Retrofit callback has onFailure where you get [Retrofit Error](http://square.github.io/retrofit/javadoc/retrofit/RetrofitError.html). Use that to determine what type of error it was.

Comment: yes I know. it works. but if I turn off the Internet, and sends the request once the timeout is triggered

Answer (score 0):

You can check the status of your connection before you perform the request using the ConnectivityManager. Look at this [guide](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Mimmo's answer.

Define a custom Interceptor class to implement the intercept(Chain chain) method. You would check the connectivity there. Throw your own Exception class if there is no connection.

Sample here: http://www.migapro.com/detect-offline-error-in-retrofit-2/

```
public class ConnectivityInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    private Context mContext;

    public ConnectivityInterceptor(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        if (!NetworkUtil.isOnline(mContext)) {
            throw new NoConnectivityException();
        }

        Request.Builder builder = chain.request().newBuilder();
        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }

}
```